# .htaccess in Wordpress for https and www to non-www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite, no-www

does anyone have any idea, why my redirection from www to non-www might not work?

Basic Info: Strato Hoster, Worpress
Domain redirection is working for: bitcoinmesse.com
Sub-Domain redirection not working: shop.bitcoinmesse.com

Current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Tried so many different things, all through the web. Most of them lead to this:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Others just said I have an infinite loop:

Again others lead to weird errors, like requesting a subfolder likte /shop/ and either getting a 404 or a https://shop/ couldn't be reached.

But none of them redirected www to non-www. Entering the address with www just always lead to: Server not found in Firefox or Website not reachable in Chrome.

Anyone has any ideas?

EDIT: Meanwhile it seemed to have an effect, and www.shop.bitcoinmesse.com is reachable and forwards to https://shop.bitcoinmesse.com.

Unfortunately a subpage like www.shop.bitcoinmesse.com/shop/ is not reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Basically right now the back-reference `$1` isn't pointing to anything. I added `(.*)` to the `RewriteRule` so that `$1` actually was a reference to a capture group in the regex. You could also try just changing `$1` to `$0` and it would do the same thing since `$0` is the full matched URL.

I also updated the RewriteCond to ensure that the host header has something after `www.`. It's a minor change, since the server shouldn't be listening to any host header anyway.

Comment: Tried your answer. Still the same result: Site not reachable, for www.shop.bitcoinmesse.com.

I really have the feeling there is more to it than something in the htaccess, as I have tried a lot of solutions an none of them seemed to have any effect on the www part.

Could it be, that the www just doesn't point to my folder with the htacces in it in any way? So maybe Strato just links the shop.bitcoinmesse.com to my subfolder, but not the www.shop.bitcoinmesse.com.

Comment: Today reaching the site with www worked. I still kept your solution. I deleted the subdomain with www.shop.bitcoinmesse.com at Strato and it still seems to work.

Unfortunately www.shop.bitcoinmesse.com/shop/ is not reachable.

Comment: If you deleted the subdomain to `www.shop` then `www.shop.bitcoinmesse.com/shop` won't load because the subdomain doesn't exist.

Comment: @Timotheus Subdomains don't usually have another `www.` subdomain on them. If you just created the `shop.` subdomain then it probably doesn't have a subdomain setup for `www.shop.`. In addition to that, depending on the hosting setup they may have separate locations for the htaccess per site (i.e. `shop.bitcoinmesse.com` and `www.bitcoinmesse.com`)

Comment: Hm, but why would www.shop.bitcoinmesse.com/shop not work if www.shop.bitcoinmesse.com works if I deleted the subdomain?
I thought creating www.shop.bitcoinmesse.com would be a double definition. So basically www.www.shop.bitcoinmesse.com.

I can define where the subdomain points to. So if I again define the www.shop.bitcoinmesse.com I can point it to the same htaccess.

Comment: @Timotheus Without seeing how you're hosting is setup, it's not easy to help. It may be worth just reaching out to your web host's support for help since they'll be able to debug and explain it the best.